# How to Uninstall node-gyp on windows through command line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, command-line

I want to uninstall node-gyp from windows 8.1 through command line is there any way to uninstall it i tried it using command

> npm uninstall node-gyp

from below link I installed node-gyp

[Link to node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#node-gyp)

but it didnt work for me i got the following error

> C:\Windows\system32>npm uninstall  node-gyp
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   open'C:\Windows\system32\pac kage.json'
>
> npm WARN system32 No description
>
> npm WARN system32 No repository field.     npm WARN system32 No
>   README data
>
> npm WARN system32 No license field.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure your working directory is at

```
nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

Then run

```
npm uninstall node-gyp
```

and it should successfully uninstall.